# User input and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, double, joptionpane

So I can't get this little snipit of code to work and I'm not sure why it wont...

```
String rawInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the three side lengths seperated by spaces.");

double[] hold = double.parseDouble(rawInput.split(" "));
```

I have an idea to use another string array to put the values in initially then put them into the double array using a for loop and the double.parseDouble() but that seems overly complicated for what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails to compile because `rawInput.split(" ")` returns an array of String objects.  You need just one `String` object to pass to `Double.parseDouble()`.  It looks like you'll need a loop, to iterate through the array that you get.

Answer (score 0):

If only it was that simple. You will have to create a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
    String rawInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the three side lengths seperated by spaces.");

    double[] doubleHold = new double[3];
    String[] stringHold = rawInput.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        doubleHold[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringHold[i]);
    }
```

I don't like how it works and think there must be a better way, anyone have that better way?

Comment: rawInput.length() is not equal to the number of doubles user enter. It won't work. You will probably get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I just fixed that, my bad

Comment: Slightly cleaner to use a for-each loop, but this is more-or-less the correct way to do it.

Comment: @DavidWallace What is a for-each loop?

Comment: My mistake, sorry.  It's not actually an improvement to use a for-each loop.

Comment: You still need the index to assign the double values. For-loop would be a more straight forward approach.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of having an `ArrayList` and using `toArray`, but I forgot that you'd still have to convert `Double` objects to primitives.

Answer (score 0):

```
String rawInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the three side lengths seperated by spaces.");
String[] inputs = rawInput.split(" ");
double[] values = new double[inputs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(inputs[i]);
}
```

Try this!

Comment: Thats almost exactly what I posted three minutes previous to you.

Comment: Yes, lukeb28, (for some small value of "three") but your solution didn't actually _work_ until after Drogba posted this.